# Firefox 3.6 performance issues & hidden boost

Tags: javascript, css, performance, firefox

Ok this is slightly mysterious. I am working on a site where a bunch transparent pngs overlay eachother and move at slightly different speeds. In firefox 3.6 this is kinda choppy.

After some research yesterday I found that by putting the images as background css I would get some performance boost. And magically it did. This morning when I turned on my computer, all this performance was gone. So I searched the internet again (opening some tabs) and *bam!* the performance was back, without changing any code.

After testing this, everytime I open 3 or 4 new tabs in a fresh firefox, the performance comes back (choppiness is totally gone). Now I guess there is some mechanism in firefox 3.6 that tells it to use more resources or something... or some hardware rendering. And I wonder if there would a way to utilize this magic when i just have one tab opened? Because it would be silly to ask the user to open 3 tabs to get optimal performance.

Comment: Firefox 3.6 performance doesn't matter anymore nowadays. It's an obsolete version.

Comment: Can't tell that to the user that will be visiting the site

Comment: Still, you are wasting your time - by the time you've designed a solution Firefox 3.6 will become just as irrelevant as Firefox 3.0 (are you testing with this one as well?). If the problem doesn't affect newer Firefox versions then waiting a little is a cheap way to solve your problem.

Comment: I suppose, I was hoping there would be an 'easy' hack. But the amount of visitors with FF3.6 doesn't go unrecognized plus the performance gain is very significant (from very choppy, to smooth as daisies). Thus seeing that FF3.6 can run it very smooth, makes me wonder how, and how can i enable this to give better perfomance to users (quite the service no?)

Comment: Also: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_firefox.asp FF3.6 still has quite the penetration rate, especially comparing against 3.5 or 3.0. Penetration rates for 3.6 started going down since November 2010, so its no IE6 we're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your video card or cpu and not firefox that is doing the magic. Especially if it's a laptop with lots of power saving functions.

Repeat your test but instead of opening 3 extra tabs, start an hd-video or other resource intensve operation in another program.

Comment: I will test this. However this applies to a recently bought quite powerful desktop, which doesn't really have many of these powersaving functions.